# Permissions issues inside a docker images

Tags: python, linux, docker, path

I've developed a Streamlit application that I'm planning to deploy on a virtual machine. To facilitate this, I've created a Dockerfile for generating Docker images. The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.10-buster

RUN mkdir -p /Projet_Linux

WORKDIR /Projet_Linux

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip && \
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install virtualenv

RUN bash ./install.sh

CMD bash main.sh
```

Within the `install.sh` file, I execute bash commands to set up the virtual environment and install necessary dependencies. The main.sh script is responsible for executing all the steps involved in my application :

```
echo "******************* Initialisation de l'application *******************"
source ./venv/bin/activate


echo "******************* Collecte des données *******************"
bash ./data_collector/collect_data.sh
echo "******************* Données collectées *******************"


echo "******************* Entraînement du modèle *******************"
bash ./data_processor/train_model.sh
echo "******************* Modèle entraîné *******************"


echo "******************* Lancement de l'application *******************"
source ./venv/bin/activate
python -m streamlit run ./application/app.py --server.port 8501
```

In the `collect_data.sh` script, I execute a Python module designed to download and automatically unzip the data into a data folder. However, I'm encountering an issue with the train_model.py file: it seems that the model, which needs to access this data, is unable to do so. When I execute the `main.sh` script, the logs display the following:

```
******************* Initialisation de l'application *******************
******************* Collecte des données *******************
Downloading face-expression-recognition-dataset.zip to ./face-expression-recognition-dataset
100%|██████████| 121M/121M [00:28<00:00, 4.51MB/s] 

******************* Données collectées *******************
******************* Entraînement du modèle *******************
Found 0 images belonging to 7 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 7 classes.
Training et test dataset initalized ✅
Model initalized ✅
model compiled ✅
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Projet_Linux/./data_processor/train_model.py", line 74, in <module>
    classifier.fit(training_set, epochs=2, validation_data=test_set, callbacks=[earlystop])
  File "/Projet_Linux/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Projet_Linux/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/preprocessing/image.py", line 103, in __getitem__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0
******************* Modèle entraîné *******************
******************* Lancement de l'application *******************

Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to False.


  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Network URL: http://172.17.0.2:8501
  External URL: http://176.179.56.212:8501
```

The `collect_data.sh` file :

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./venv/bin/activate
python3 ./data_collector/collect.py

mkdir "data"
mv face-expression-recognition-dataset data
```

and a snippet of the `train_model.py`

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory='/ProjetLinux/data/face-expression-recognition-dataset/images/train',
                                              target_size=(48, 48),
                                              class_mode='categorical',
                                              batch_size=32,
                                              classes=['Angy', 'Disgust', 'Fear',
                                                       'Happy', 'Neutral', 'Sad',
                                                       'Surprise'])
```

I've already tried several paths ("./data/...", "./ProjetLinux/data/...", ...) but none of them works. I also attempted to access the inside of the Docker images, and found that the data has been correctly downloaded.

Why is the model (and the application overall) unable to access the data?